# Obtaining handle to key with NtCreateKey/NtOpenKey

Tags: c, winapi, registry

**PURPOSE**

I'm trying to make a function which will create a given sub key in the HKCU registry hive, or open the sub key if it already exists, then return TRUE.

**NOTES**

Let `RegSidPath` represent a fully qualified HKCU registry path with an `user SID` appended to it such as `\\Registry\\User\\S-1-5-20-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-1050`

Let `KeyToCreate` represent a specific registry path such as `\\Software\\MyCompany\\MySoftware\\MySubKey`

**CODE**

I have the following function:

```
BOOL CreateHKCUKey(PWCHAR RegSidPath, PWCHAR KeyToCreate) {

UNICODE_STRING uString;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&uString, RegSidPath);

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjAttributes;
InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjAttributes, &uString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, 0, 0);

HANDLE BaseKeyHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS Status = NtOpenKey(&BaseKeyHandle, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, &ObjAttributes);
if (NT_SUCCESS(Status) && Status != STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND) {

    UNICODE_STRING KeyString = { 0 };
    do {
        PWCHAR NextSubKey = StrStrW((KeyString.Length == 0 ? KeyToCreate : KeyString.Buffer) + 1, L"\\");
        DWORD CurrentKeyLength = lstrlenW(KeyToCreate) - lstrlenW(NextSubKey);
        PWCHAR CurrentSubKey = PWCHAR(GlobalAlloc(GPTR, CurrentKeyLength + sizeof(WCHAR)));
        if (CurrentSubKey != ERROR) {
            memcpy(CurrentSubKey, KeyToCreate, CurrentKeyLength * sizeof(WCHAR));
            CurrentSubKey[CurrentKeyLength] = UNICODE_NULL;

            RtlInitUnicodeString(&KeyString, CurrentSubKey);

            OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES KeyAttributes;
            InitializeObjectAttributes(&KeyAttributes, &KeyString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, &BaseKeyHandle, 0);

            HANDLE CurrentHiveEntry = NULL;
            Status = NtOpenKey(&CurrentHiveEntry, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, &KeyAttributes);
            if (RtlNtStatusToDosError(Status) == ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME) {
                InitializeObjectAttributes(&KeyAttributes, &KeyString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, &CurrentHiveEntry, 0);

                DWORD DefaultDisposition;
                Status = NtCreateKey(&CurrentHiveEntry, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, &KeyAttributes, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, &DefaultDisposition);
                if (NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
                    if (StrCmpNW(KeyString.Buffer + uString.Length, KeyString.Buffer, lstrlenW(KeyToCreate) == 0)) 
                        return TRUE;
                    else continue;
                } else break;
            } else break;
            BaseKeyHandle = CurrentHiveEntry;
        }
    } while (TRUE);
 }
 NtClose(BaseKeyHandle);
 return FALSE;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

Whenever the code gets to this part of the function

```
Status = NtOpenKey(&CurrentHiveEntry, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, &KeyAttributes);
        if (RtlNtStatusToDosError(Status) == ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME) {
```

The return value is always `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME (161)` even if the current sub key already exists.

**QUESTION**

What is the reason, and what am I doing wrong? Is there anything that I've done which is not correct, and how can I fix it?

Comment: At the point of failure, what is the value of `CurrentSubKey` ?  Also, the only error you check for is `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME`, if the previous loop failed with any other error code then `BaseKeyHandle` won't be pointing where you expect it to.  (Oh, and you're leaking handles.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston `\\Software` - so what can i do to debug the error

Comment: Why do you need the NT API for this?

Comment: show status, but not converted win32 error. `ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME` can be from `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_INVALID` or from `STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_SYNTAX_BAD`

Comment: you conditions like `NT_SUCCESS(Status) && Status != STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` senseless. if `NT_SUCCESS(Status)` - can not be `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: and when you do **relative** open - the path must not begin from \

Comment: `InitializeObjectAttributes(&KeyAttributes, &KeyString, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, &BaseKeyHandle, 0);` `&BaseKeyHandle` !! instead `BaseKeyHandle` - code full of mistakes and **very** not effective

Comment: for what you need allocate memory ?? `GlobalAlloc`. and where memory free ??.

Comment: This would be so much simpler if you used [`RegCreateKeyEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844.aspx) instead.  It handles all the logic of creating intermediate keys for you if they don't already exist.  1 function call, no looping needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NTSTATUS CreateKey(PHANDLE KeyHandle, ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, PWCHAR RegSidPath, PWCHAR KeyToCreate, PULONG Disposition) 
{
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, RegSidPath);

    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName ,OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenKey(&oa.RootDirectory, KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY, &oa);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        ObjectName.Buffer = KeyToCreate;

        do 
        {
            ACCESS_MASK Access;

            if (KeyToCreate = wcschr(++ObjectName.Buffer, '\\'))
            {
                ObjectName.Length = (USHORT)RtlPointerToOffset(ObjectName.Buffer, KeyToCreate);
                Access = KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY;
            }
            else
            {
                ObjectName.Length = (USHORT)wcslen(ObjectName.Buffer) * sizeof(WCHAR);
                Access = DesiredAccess;
            }

            ObjectName.MaximumLength = ObjectName.Length;

            status = ZwCreateKey(KeyHandle, Access, &oa, 0, 0, 0, Disposition);

            NtClose(oa.RootDirectory);

            oa.RootDirectory = *KeyHandle;

        } while (0 <= status && (ObjectName.Buffer = KeyToCreate));
    }

    return status;
}
```

and use as

```
  HANDLE hKey;
  NTSTATUS status = CreateKey(&hKey, KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
    L"\\REGISTRY\\USER\\S-***", 
    L"\\Software\\MyCompany\\MySoftware\\MySubKey", 0);
```

Comment: @Castiel - what you mean under *still* ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are writing a driver, use [`RegCreateKeyEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844.aspx) instead. It handles all the logic of creating intermediate keys for you if they don't already exist. 1 function call, no looping needed.

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwDisposition;
LONG lRet = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_USERS, L"S-1-5-20-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-1050\\Software\\MyCompany\\MySoftware\\MySubKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, samDesired, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisposition);
if (lRet == 0)
{
    ...
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

However, to access the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive of a specific user, the preferred solution is to use [`RegOpenCurrentUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894.aspx) or [`LoadUserProfile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx) instead of accessing `HKEY_USERS` directly:

```
// impersonate the desired user first, then...

HKEY hRootKey;
LONG lRet = RegOpenCurrentUser(samDesired, &hRootKey);
if (lRet == 0)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    lRet = RegCreateKeyExW(hRootKey, L"Software\\MyCompany\\MySoftware\\MySubKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, samDesired, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisposition);
    if (lRet == 0)
    {
        ...
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    RegCloseKey(hRootKey);
}

// stop impersonating...
```

```
// obtain token to desired user first, then...

PROFILEINFO profile = {0};
profile.dwSize = sizeof(profile);
profile.dwFlags = PI_NOUI;

if (LoadUserProfile(hToken, &profile))
{
    HKEY hKey;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    LONG lRet = RegCreateKeyExW((HKEY)profile.hProfile, L"Software\\MyCompany\\MySoftware\\MySubKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, samDesired, NULL, &hKey, &dwDisposition);
    if (lRet == 0)
    {
        ...
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    UnloadUserProfile(hToken, profile.hProfile);
}

// release token ...
```

Comment: I'm aware of how to use Advapi32 , thanks but I was looking for NTAPI calls. The latter is very well documented everywhere else.